Regex for pH range factored to 0.5
I'm trying to write a javascript input mask to accept pH values ie. 0-14, but also allowing optional .0 and .5
So valid values would include 0, 0.0, 0.5, 13.5 and 14, 14.0
options.regex = "^[0-9]{1}|1[0-4](\\.[0,5]{1})?$";

This works up to a point but trying to combine the optional decimal with the max of 14 is doing my head in.

Why not convert to number and check trivially?

The way you currently have it, the optional decimal part is only allowed in the 10-14 case, not 0-9.  You need to group both integer options together - something like "^([0-9]|1[0-4])(\\.[05])?$".  Note that I've also removed the {1}s which are pointless (that's the default behavior), and removed the comma in the decimal part (which would actually allow a comma instead of a zero or five).

You need a separate alternative for the 14, 14(?:\.0)?, and group these alternatives. ^(?:(?:[0-9]|1[0-3])(?:\\.[05])?|14(?:\\.0)?)$

Regex
^(0?\d|1[0-3])(\.[05])?$|^14(\.0)?$
Explanation

(0?\d|1[0-3]): 0X [0 > X > 9] OR 1X [0 > X > 3]
(\.[05])? : Optional .0 OR .5
14(\.0)?: Deal with the case 14. Will not match 14.5

Matching set
0.0
3.5
7.0
12.5
14.0
8.0
4.5
11.0
2.0
6.5
9.0
13.5
1.0
10.5
5.0
6
9
2
7.5
14
0.5
11
3
5.0
12.5
8
1.0
10.5
4
13

Non-matching set
-1.5
16.3
2.7
7.8
14.9
0.2
18.4
-0.7
5.6
20.1
8.9
1.3
-3.0
25.7
4.2
6.2
9.7
2.3
7.1
14.4
0.9
11.8
3.6
5.4
12.9
8.3
1.7
10.2
4.8
13.6
14.5

Edit note:
Re-Edited following the tips of @Wiktor Stribiżew. Thanks.

This ^(0?\d|1[0-4])(\.[0|5])?$ is wrong because it matches a number beyond 14. It also matches a non-number like 5.|. Demo.

I doubt ^(0?\d|1[0-3])(\.[05])?$|14(\.0)?$ is what OP needs since it can find a match in WHat's up 14, demo.

I've correct it again. We now got similar patterns except I've repeated the ^ and $ and didn't used non-capturing groups.
By the way, special thanks for having pointed my [0|5] which was definitively wrong.
